# MySQL MATCH(field) AGAINST('string') works for some, doesnt for others

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table like below:

```
phrase1    phrase2
ssd        solid state drive
ps 4       playstation 4
```

Both columns `phrase1` and `phrase2` are `FULLTEXT`.

I issue the following query:

```
select * from phrases
where match(phrase1) against('ssd' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR match(phrase2) against('ssd' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I get back:

```
+----+-------------------+---------+
| id | phrase1           | phrase2 |
+----+-------------------+---------+
|  1 | solid state drive | ssd     |
+----+-------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I when I issue:

```
select * from phrases
where match(phrase1) against('ps 4' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR match(phrase2) against('ps 4' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I get this:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Here are some variables on fulltext.

```
> show variables like 'ft_%';
+--------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name            | Value          |
+--------------------------+----------------+
| ft_boolean_syntax        | + -><()~*:""&| |
| ft_max_word_len          | 84             |
| ft_min_word_len          | 1              |
| ft_query_expansion_limit | 20             |
| ft_stopword_file         | (built-in)     |
+--------------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE to search for strings with spaces.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

So your code will be :

```
select * from phrases
where match(phrase1) against('ps 4' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
OR match(phrase2) against('ps 4' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Let me know If this works for you

Comment: empty set still, makes no difference. the space is not the problem because i can search for "solid state drive" and it works. the problem is it doesnt count 1 or 2 letter words, even though i set `ft_min_word_len` to 1, and rebuilt the indexes

Comment: By reading from various Sites I can say that only ft_min_word_len = 3 is minimum configurable word limit to search. Just to test try use this query. select * from phrases
where match(phrase1) against("+ps +4" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR match(phrase2) against("+ps +4" IN BOOLEAN MODE);  Just try this, lets see If this works